# How to list all used typescript types in a project

Tags: typescript

Consider the following code from my project.

```
describe('Feature active', () => {
  it('Should render a Feature', () => {
    const wrapper = shallow(<MyComponent prop1={1}/>);
    expect(wrapper.prop('prop1')).to.equal(1);
  });
});
```

Typescript can resolve the type of `describe` and `it` using `@types/jest`. I can confirm this by setting `types: []` in my tsconfig.json and tsc fails. I need to explicitly set `types: [ '@types/jest' ]` in my project as my project fails because of types clashes between jest and mocha.

I want to understand how compilerOption.types work in a bit more detail and to that effect I want to get a list of all such packages(like `@types/jest`) which typescript is actively using in my project.

I can see that I have a lot of `@types/...` packages in my package.json but my `tsc` command works just fine even with a single inclusion `types: [ '@types/jest' ]`, does that mean other types are not being used by tsc?

Now, is there a way or a command which can list all the types tsc compiler is using to transpile my code?

Answer (score 1):

Other `@types/...` packages are used when you import a module and `node_modules/@types` is declared in [`typeRoots`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#typeRoots) (by default, that is implicit).

`jest` in [`types`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#types) makes it available in the global scope, i.e. you don't need to import their helper methods like `describe` or `it` etc.